# SwiftUI onTapGesture interact with caller only

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've just started looking into SwiftUI and since it's so different I'm trying to wrap my head around basic concepts.

In this scenario, how would I go about changing the color only for the circle tapped?

```swift
ForEach(1...count, id: \.self) { _ in
    Circle()
        .foregroundColor(colors.randomElement()).opacity(0.2)
        .frame(width: .random(in: 10...100), height: .random(in: 10...100))
        .position(x: .random(in: self.stepperValue...400),
                  y: .random(in: self.stepperValue...400))
        .saturation(2.0)
        .onTapGesture(count: 1, perform: {
            // Change color of circle that was tapped
            print("Tapped")
        })
        .animation(.default) // Animate the change in position

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a `View` that has the "Rows" individual properties

```
import SwiftUI
struct SampleColorChangeView: View {
    //If the options are fixed no need to keep an eye on them
    //You can move this down to the Row if you don't need to have them available here
    let colors: [Color] = [.red,.blue,.gray, .yellow,.orange]
    @State var count: Int = 10
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach(1...count, id: \.self) { _ in
                RowView(colors: colors)
                
            }
        }
    }
}
//Create a row View to observe individual objects
//You will do this with anything that you want to Observe independently
struct RowView: View {
    let colors: [Color]
    //@State observes changes so the View is updated
    @State var color: Color = .blue
    //This kind of works like the colors do you want one for each or a shared for all. Does the parent need access? You can move it up or keep it here
    @State var stepperValue: CGFloat = 0
    //The only change here is the reference to the individual Color
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            //You set the individual color here
            .foregroundColor(color).opacity(0.2)
            .frame(width: .random(in: 10...100), height: .random(in: 10...100))
            .position(x: .random(in: self.stepperValue...400),
                      y: .random(in: self.stepperValue...400))
            .saturation(2.0)
            .onTapGesture(count: 1, perform: {
                // Change color of circle that was tapped
                color = colors.randomElement()!
                print("Tapped")
            })
            .animation(.default) // Animate the change in position
            //If you want to set a random color to start vs just having them all be the same Color you can do something like this
            .onAppear(){
                color = colors.randomElement()!
            }
    }
}
struct SampleColorChangeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SampleColorChangeView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well there are two main options I see here

1. Make a custom view like

```
struct MyCircle: View {

    @State var color: Color?

    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .foregroundColor(color)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.color = colors.randomElement()
            }
    }
}
```

and then integrate that or

2. Use a model for your color

```
struct MyView: View {
    
    @State var colors = allColors.indices.compactMap { _ in allColors.randomElement() }
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(colors.indices) { index in
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(colors[index])
                .onTapGesture {
                    colors[index] = allColors.randomElement()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

A state like this should preferably be in its own class which should be inserted as `ObservedObject`.

Comment: Wouldn't the `Array(repeating:count:)` repeat the same color? You probably want something more like `allColors.indices.compactMap { _ in allColors.randomElement() }`.

Comment: Ah my bad, missed that part. Elegant solution there!