# SwiftUI Animating System Image Contained in a NavigationLink Label

Tags: list, animation, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

The following code is supposed provide a short confirmation animation when a selected row has been added to 'favourites'. The issue however is that when you tap one, they all animate. Why is this, and how do I resolve the issue?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
class Favourites: ObservableObject {
    var favAnimals: Set<String> = []
    
    func contains(_ animal: String) -> Bool {
        favAnimals.contains(animal)
    }
    
    func add(_ animal: String) {
        objectWillChange.send()
        favAnimals.insert(animal)
    }
    
    func remove(_ animal: String) {
        objectWillChange.send()
        favAnimals.remove(animal)
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let animals = ["Dog", "Cat", "Horse", "Sheep"]
    
    @StateObject var favourites = Favourites()
    @State private var tapped = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(animals, id: \.self) { animal in 
                NavigationLink { 
                    Text("Animal Detail View")
                } label: { 
                    HStack {
                        Text(animal)
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: favourites.contains(animal) ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
                            .foregroundColor(favourites.contains(animal) ? .red : .gray)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                tapped.toggle()
                                if favourites.contains(animal) {
                                    favourites.remove(animal)
                                } else {
                                    favourites.add(animal)
                                }
                                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2, execute: {
                                    tapped = false
                                })
                            }
                            .scaleEffect(tapped ? 1.2 : 1)
                            .animation(.spring(response: 0.4, dampingFraction: 0.6), value: tapped)
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Animals")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replicating the suggested answer: [SwiftUI onTapGesture interact with caller only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67505299/swiftui-ontapgesture-interact-with-caller-only) I was able to play around with the code until I found a solution which worked for my scenario which was to create the heart icon in it's own View with the .onTapGesture modifier attached to it.

This may be bloated way of achieving the result but as a novice I'm pretty happy!

```
class Favourites: ObservableObject {
    var favAnimals: Set<String> = []
    
    func contains(_ animal: String) -> Bool {
        favAnimals.contains(animal)
    }
    
    func add(_ animal: String) {
        objectWillChange.send()
        favAnimals.insert(animal)
    }
    
    func remove(_ animal: String) {
        objectWillChange.send()
        favAnimals.remove(animal)
    }
    
}

struct FavouriteIcon: View {
    @StateObject var favourites = Favourites()
    @State private var tapped = false
    let animal: String
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: favourites.contains(animal) ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
            .foregroundColor(favourites.contains(animal) ? .red : .gray)
            .onTapGesture {
                tapped.toggle()
                if favourites.contains(animal) {
                    favourites.remove(animal)
                } else {
                    favourites.add(animal)
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2, execute: {
                    tapped = false
                })
            }
            .scaleEffect(tapped ? 1.2 : 1)
            .animation(.spring(response: 0.1, dampingFraction: 0.9), value: tapped)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let animals = ["Dog", "Cat", "Horse", "Sheep"]
    
    @StateObject var favourites = Favourites()
    @State private var tapped = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(animals, id: \.self) { animal in 
                NavigationLink { 
                    Text("Animal Detail View")
                } label: { 
                    HStack {
                        Text(animal)
                        Spacer()
                        FavouriteIcon(animal: animal)
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Animals")
        }
    }
}
```