# Change Background Color of selected button item swiftui in foreach

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, foreach

View :

```
    struct SubCatProductView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var vm = SubCategoryViewModel()
    @State private var hasError = false
    
    @State private var selectedSubCat = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            subcategory
            product
        }
        .task {
            vm.subcatRequest()
       }
    }
}
```

SubCategory View & Product View :

OnAppear in SubCategory View : It doesn't work as per your suggestion

```
private extension SubCatProductView {

var subcategory: some View {
    
    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        
        HStack {
            
            ForEach(vm.subcategories, id: \.id) { subcategory in
                Button {
                    print("selected SubCategory",subcategory.name)
                    selectedSubCat = subcategory.name
                    vm.getProducts(subcat_id: subcategory.id)
                } label: {
                    SubCatView(subcategory: subcategory)
                }
                .background((selectedSubCat == subcategory.name ? Color.yellow : Color.clear))
            }
        }
    }
    .onAppear {
        print("onAppear : ",selectedSubCat)
        if let first = vm.subcategories.first {
            print("selected Sub Cat in onTask : ",first.name)
            selectedSubCat = first.name
        }
    }
}

var product: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(vm.products, id: \.id) { product in
            ProductView(product: product)
        }
    }
}
```

}

ViewModel :

In this viewmodel, i have two api calls . the flow is

1. first api call -> receives data -> get 0th data from the array and display the array in scroll view horizontally.
2. pass the 0th data as a parameter to second api call and get the another data and display it

   ```
    final class SubCategoryViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var subcategories : [SubData] = []
    @Published var products : [ProductData] = []
    func subcatRequest() {

        let url = "https://auroraa.site/suresh-packers/admin/api/get-sub-category-api.php"

        AF.request(url, method: .post,
                   parameters: ["type": "get_sub_category","category": "1"],
                   encoding: URLEncoding.default,
                   headers: nil,
                   interceptor: nil).response { responce in

            switch responce.result {

            case .success(let data):
                do {
                    let jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode(SubCategory.self, from: data!)
                    print("Category Names : ",jsonData)
                    self.subcategories = jsonData.data
                    self.getProducts(subcat_id: self.subcategories[0].id)
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }

    func getProducts(subcat_id : String) {

        let productsurl = "https://auroraa.site/suresh-packers/admin/api/get-products.php"

        AF.request(productsurl, method: .post,
                   parameters: ["type": "get_products","sub_category": subcat_id],
                   encoding: URLEncoding.default,
                   headers: nil,
                   interceptor: nil).response { responce in

            switch responce.result {

            case .success(let data):
                do {
                    let jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Products.self, from: data!)
                    print("Product Names : ",jsonData)
                    self.products = jsonData.data
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }}
   ```

my requirement is : when i open the page horizontal items are get from api and shown but i need to make first item selectable defaulty
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPKhT.jpg

Comment: Move the `Button` to another view and use an `@State` variable in that view.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI onTapGesture interact with caller only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67505299/swiftui-ontapgesture-interact-with-caller-only)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this approach using a `@State var selection`, and `.background` modifier
on the `Button`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let arr = ["item-1","item-2","item-3","item-4"]
    @State var selection = "" // <-- here, adjust to subcategory type
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(arr, id: \.self) { subcategory in
                    Button {
                        print("selected SubCategory",subcategory)
                        // vm.getProducts(subcat_id: subcategory.id)
                        selection = subcategory  // <-- here
                    } label: {
                        //  SubCatView(subcategory: subcategory)
                        Text(subcategory)
                    }
                    // --- here
                    .background((selection == subcategory ? Color.yellow : Color.clear))
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            if let first = arr.first {
                selection = first  // <-- here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks .but by default how to make first item selectable @workingdog support Ukraine

Comment: updated my answer with a possible solution to make the first item selected

Comment: sorry , i got array from viewmodel as api call result , so it couldn't possible to access the array in onAppear... please give me another solution @workingdog support Ukraine

Comment: you will have to show more code, I cannot guess what you are doing. Nevertheless, the `.onAppear{...}` is usually a very appropriate place to do this. Try it, let us know what does not work.

Comment: just to be clear, you would use `if let first = vm.subcategories.first {...}`

Comment: i have updated my code as per your suggestions ..please review it .. onAppear code still didn't work @workingdog support Ukraine

Comment: You have multiple problems in your code. Specifically, `func subcatRequest` and `func getProducts`
 are asynchronous functions. Look up asynchronous functions and how to use them,
 for example using `completion` handler.

 In `SubCatProductView`, try moving the `.onAppear{...}` to the `ForEach{...}.onAppear { if let first = vm.subcategories.first {...}}`, not the `ScrollView(.horizontal) {...}`

Comment: I would also replace `.task{vm.subcatRequest()}` with `.onAppear{vm.subcatRequest()}`.
 `.task{..}` is used when you have a `async/await` Task concurrency function.

 Also, in `func subcatRequest` try using `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.subcategories = jsonData.data }`
 Similarly in `func getProducts`, `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.products = jsonData.data}`

Comment: yes its working thanks @workingdog support Ukraine