# How to pass parameters to body root view modifier in SwiftUI correctly?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I use a list view to display structs in my view (specifically, let's say comments). Comments have their own struct and are identifiable:

```
@State private var showDeletePrompt = false

ForEach(comments) { comment in
    CommentView(comment: comment)
        .swipeActions(allowsFullSwipe: false) {
            Button {
                showDeletePrompt.toggle()
            } label: {
                Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
            }
        }
}
```

As you can see, once a row is swiped, it can be deleted, but first `showDeletePrompt` is being toggled. The purpose toggling this state variable is to present an alert that is attached to the root view of the `body`:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        ...
        ForEach(comments) { comment in
            ...the code snippet above...
        }
        ...
    }
    .alert("Are you sure?", isPresented: $showDeleteIntent) {
        Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) { }
        Button("Delete", role: .destructive) {
            --> deleteComment(comment: comment) // the issue is here
        }
    }
}
```

When "Delete" is tapped the `deleteComment` method should be called to post a HTTP request. And here is my question, what is the best practice to pass which comment should be deleted from inner swipe action method to root view's alert modifier?

What I have already tried is to define a state that would hold a copy of the comment that was swiped to be deleted and then this copy is used in alert modifier to call the `deleteComment` but this feels non-standard and unusual to me in SwiftUI. At least, I haven't met such an approach before.

Will be glad to see your thoughts on the best practices.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI onTapGesture interact with caller only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67505299/swiftui-ontapgesture-interact-with-caller-only)

Comment: @loremipsum not quite, the answers either show how to modify variable withing the view's modifier itself or using additional state variable as I described in the solution that I tried

Comment: You’ll need a another state variable no matter what, you either need a selected comment variable or a presented variable for the row.

Comment: That's what actually what I wanted to know, whether it's the only best and right solution. Thank you for help