# calling sheet(isPresented) from inside a ForEach loop always links to first instance

Tags: swiftui, foreach

EDIT: Not sure why this was marked as a duplicate of [SwiftUI onTapGesture interact with caller only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67505299/swiftui-ontapgesture-interact-with-caller-only) as that question has nothing to do with presenting a sheet.

I have an array of Table objects that are iterated over in a ForEach, showing the name of each table as a button, that when clicked brings up an edit sheet (EditTable) for that particular table. Well, that's what it's supposed to do. The button labels `table.name` are all correct and unique, but no matter which one I press it opens up the first table in the array. I suspect this might have something to do with the fact that `showSheetEditTable` is reused in each pass through the loop, but I don't know how to correct for that.

```
@State var tables: [Table]
@State var showSheetTable = false

...    

ForEach(tables) { table in
    VStack {
        Button(table.name) {
            self.showSheetTable.toggle()
        }
        .font(.headline)
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheetTable) {
            EditTable(table: table)
        }
    }
}
```

---

[jnpdx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560942/jnpdx) solved it! For anyone else who runs into this, I've now got the following code and it works properly.

```
@State var tables: [Table]
@State var selectedTable: Table? = nil

...    

ForEach(tables) { table in
    VStack {
        Button(table.name) {
            selectedTable = table
        }
        .font(.headline)
        }
    }
}
.sheet(item: $selectedTable) { table in
    EditTable(table: table)
}
```

Comment: Use `sheet(item:)` instead of `sheet(isPresented:)`. And, put the `sheet` outside of the `ForEach`

Comment: Brilliant! That did the trick.